# matplotlib does not show window

Tags: python, matplotlib, raspbian

matplotlib on raspberry pi3 for a simple code not working.

My code gets:

```
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

I tried using `matplotlib.use('Agg')`. I don't get the error but it does not show any graph, with `matplotlib.use('TkAgg')` I get an error too.

I have checked the backend:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.get_backend()
# 'TkAgg'
```

Can anyone tell me where the problem is?

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

plt.plot([1,2,3],[5,6,7])

plt.show()
```

Comment: Improved formatting and grammar

Comment: You are running this on a server without display. You can activate graphical output for your server, or you can forward graphical output via the connection you use.

Comment: thank you. How can I do it?